# Matrix transformation applied to a rectangle.What is the area of the resulting figure?

Tags: matrices, vectors

> Consider the rectangle formed by the points $(2,7),(2,6),(4,7)$ and
>   $(4,6)$. Is it still a rectangle after transformation by $\underline
>  A$= $ \left( \begin{matrix}  3&1 \\ 2&\frac {1}{2} \\ \end{matrix}
>  \right) $ ?By what factor has its area changed ?

I've defined the point $(2,6)$ as the origin of my vectors $\vec v $ and $\vec u$ with
 $\vec v = \left(\begin{matrix}0 \\1  \\\end{matrix} \right)$ and $\vec u = \left(\begin{matrix}2 \\0  \\\end{matrix} \right)$ which get transformed to $\underline A \vec v=$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 \\\frac{1}{2}  \\\end{matrix} \right)$ and $\underline A \vec u=$$\left(\begin{matrix}6 \\4  \\\end{matrix} \right)$.

So my new figure(which is not a rectangle anymore,but is now a parallelogram) has vertices $(2,6)(3,6  \frac{1}{2}),(8,10)$ and $(9,10 \frac{1}{2})$

Now the rectangle has area equal to $2 \cdot 1=2$, and after the transformation I have that the area of the resulting parallelogram is  $\underline A \vec v \times \underline A \vec u =|1\cdot 4 -\cfrac{1}{2}\cdot 6|=1$

Now my problem is that when I calculate the area by geometric methods I have:

[image]

You see I get a different answer,so it's clear that I've had it all wrong since the beginning but I don't see where.

I upload now the image of the parallelogram where I've applied law of cosines in the last step of the above image.

[image]

I've tried to be as specific as possible about my steps.Can someone help me  ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\det A = - {1 \over 2}$, so you would expect the area to be halved.

Comment: Your computation of the angle between $u,v$ is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed it gets halved if I work out the area only by the determinant.But when I work it out with geometry I get that the area is $ \approx 9$

Comment: Like I wrote, your computation of the angle is incorrect.

Comment: where's the precise wrong calculation\number ?

Comment: There are not that many steps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the cosine rule:

$\cos \theta = {\|u\|^2 +\|v\|^2 - \|u-v\|^2 \over 2 \|u\| \|v\| } = {52 +{5 \over 4} - {149 \over 4} \over 2 \sqrt{ 52 } \sqrt{{5 \over 4} } }$.

You are missing a square root or two.

Comment: Let me work it out again,me dumb.Thanks for you time !

Comment: No problem. I make far more egregious errors on a regular basis.

Comment: If you will excuse my being patronising; I tell my kids to write out the formula in symbols first before substituting actual values. This eliminates many errors like the above.

Comment: One last question :I get that the resulting area is $1/2$ shouldn't it be $1$ or am I misinterpreting the result ?(Btw your advice is really welcomed,I've spent quite some time figuring out where my mistake was before asking the question here on the site.....)

Comment: The resulting area is one. Compute $\|u\| \|v\| \sin \theta$. Just do it on a calculator first. $\cos \theta \approx 0.9923$. $\sin \theta \approx 0.1240$.

Comment: Lol..One computational error after the other.I better go to sleep now...I am really gratefull for your help @copper.hat. Thanks again.

Comment: Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

I'd transform each point, not the basis.  By doing what you did, you've effectively moved the rectangle so that one of its vertices is the origin.

For example,

$$\underline{A}P_1=  \left( \begin{matrix}  3&1 \\ 2&\frac {1}{2} \\ \end{matrix}\right) \left( \begin{matrix}  2 \\ 7 \\ \end{matrix}
 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix}  13 \\ 7.5 \\ \end{matrix}
 \right).$$

The transformed points, in order, are $(13, 7.5), (12, 7), (19, 11.5), (18, 11)$.

From here, you need to choose your basis carefully.  The two vectors have to start at the same point and go along adjacent sides.  If you choose $(2,7)$ in the original frame, the bases go from there to $(2,6)$ and $(4,7)$.  This means that your basis, for the sake of this calculation, is

$$\left( \begin{matrix}  0 \\ -1 \\ \end{matrix}
 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix}  2 \\ 0 \\ \end{matrix}
 \right)$$

The basis in the transformed frame must do likewise.

Comment: Don't we need a point to define where our vectors start ?How is it that I have just moved my rectangle when the resulting figure is not anymore a rectangle but only a parallelogram ?I am really confused..how the exercise was supposed to be solved ? Thanks for you time @Jhon.

Comment: The issue here is purely computational. The OP's approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: Edited my answer.  I wasn't really hitting on the real issue.

Comment: @copper.hat you're correct.  I edited my answer to note that the points themselves don't need to be transformed in this case.  (Actually, come to think of it, the directions of the basis vectors don't really matter either, do they?)